# Bamboo deployment starts but never finishes

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, bamboo

I have a bamboo job which builds artifacts (.zip and deploy.cmd). This finishes succesfully. Then I download the shared artifacts and attempt to deploy using a script:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe website.deploy.cmd
```

and arguments:

```
/y /m:https://websiteAddress.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/MSDeploy.axd 
/a:basic 
/u:$username
/p:password /Y
```

This starts fine and then the log displays this:

```
24-Oct-2017 10:17:41    
24-Oct-2017 10:17:41    C:\Bamboo\build-dir\5275649-5439489>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe website.deploy.cmd 
24-Oct-2017 10:17:41    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
24-Oct-2017 10:17:41    (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
24-Oct-2017 10:17:41
```

However, nothing happens even if I leave it running for a very long time. The publish functionality works fine when I do publish from Visual Studio. There are no further logs or errors. What could be the reason for this deployment script never to appear to do any kind of work?

Comment: Could you please share the details about the website.deploy.cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was closing due to an incorrect path. No error was shown, however having logged onto the remote machine and run the query from there I was able to see the problem